# Session has value but is not recognised

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering why does the `Session` doesn't seem to remain it's value but it actually prints its value?
I print out the the value of the `Session` but when I access the same page on a different tab it doesn't recognize that it has a value. 
Also when the page is refreshed `Session` becomes null...?
And another thing I'm not sure if what I did in the `Log Out` button is correct

This is what I have in my `LogInController.php`

```
<?php

class LogInController extends BaseController {
    public function actionLogIn() {
        $username = Input::get('username');
        $password = Input::get('password');
        if(($username == 'batman' and $password == '12345') or ($username == 'robin' and $password == '54321')){
            Session::put('username', $username);
            return Redirect::route('welcome')
                ->with('username', $username)
                ->with('title', 'Welcome!');

        }else {
            Session::flush();
            return Redirect::to('login')
                ->with('asterisk', 'Invalid username or password')
                ->with('title', 'Login');
        }
    }
    public function actionLogOut() {
        Session::flush();
        return View::make('login.formlogin')
            ->with('title', 'Login');
    }
}
```

Here's `routes.php`

```
Route::get('/', function()
    { return View::make('hello'); });

Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login', function ()
    { return View::make('login.formlogin')
        ->with('title', 'Login'); 
    }));

Route::post('login', array('uses'=>'LogInController@actionLogIn'));

Route::get('error', array('uses'=>'LogInController@actionLogOut'));

Route::get('welcome', array('as' => 'welcome', function ()
    { return View::make('login.uservalid'); }));
```

`formlogin.blade.php`

```
@extends('login.login')
@section('content')
    <h3>Login</h3>
    {{ Form::open(array('method'=>'post')) }}
        <div id="asterisk">{{ Session::get('asterisk') }}</div>
        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username:') }}
        {{ Form::text('username') }}<br/>
        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:') }}
        {{ Form::password('password') }}<br/>
        {{ Form::submit('Log In') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
@endsection
```

`uservalid.php`

```
@extends('login.layouts')
@section('content')


    {{ Form::open(array('method'=>'get')) }}
        welcome
        {{ Session::get('username') }}
        <br/>
        {{ Form::submit('Log Out') }}
    {{ Form::close(0) }}

@endsection
```

`layouts.blade.php` for `uservalid.blade.php`

```
<html>
<header>
    <title></title>
</header>
<body>
    @if(Session::has('username'))
        @yield('content')
    @else
        nothing to do here
    @endif
</body>
</html>
```

thanks,

Comment: Check session_start(); if it is not started value will not recognize.

Comment: @Salim I got this error `ErrorException
A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()` even though I haven't add this before.. I know that in PHP this must be declared first but I'm not sure with Laravel that's why I didn't add anything like this

Comment: I dont understand your code logic - why are you not using the Auth class? It seems like your trying to repeat exactly what already exists in laravel

Comment: @TheShiftExchange this just serves as a practice in using `Sessions` as I am new to Laravel, I intentionally used a simple string comparison for the log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
<?php
$username = Session::get('username');
?>
```

and

```
{{ Session::flash('username', $username) }}
```

in `uservalid.php`
so when page is refreshed it display the same page (which is correct) and also when page is open in new window, it doesn't log out or anything now unlike before

it kinda seem iffy to me though .. any suggestion/s ?

Answer (score 0):

Really, you should probably be using the `Auth` class for something like this, you'll find it handles all the session-related authentication stuff for you.