# Usage of Session::put and Session::flash

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I understand that `Session::put`, stores item in the `Session` which remains in the whole project until `Session::flush` (correct me if I'm wrong)
while `Session::flash` stores item only for the next request.
ref: http://four.laravel.com/docs/session

But what I don't understand is in reference to this
[Session has value but is not recognised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571443/session-has-value-but-is-not-recognised)
where `Session` doesn't work when page is refreshed, then I tried using `Session::flash` instead which seem to solve my problem.
I simply want to understand this `Session` in Laravel. I'm new to Laravel but I've used php and its `Session` but they're somewhat different from what I've experienced. Can anybody clear this out for me?
Thanks, it would be a great help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty much spot on, `Session::put()` will place something in the session for the lifetime of the session and `Session::flash()` will only be available on the next request. Make sure that you only interact with the session in your controllers (and, if you absolutely have to, your models) so that you aren't dealing with mixed up session data in your views.

Comment: I didn't use any models because as I have said earlier this project has no database. I only use `Session in Views and Controllers.

Comment: Okay, be aware that people aren't going to read through all your questions to know more about your project. You mention nowhere in this question that you do not intend to use a database.